# How to get text glow to properly export to SVG?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, export, svg

I have an Excel chart with some color regions and Black text over them, and I use a "glow" effect, with White color for the glow, to differentiate them from the background. So far, so good.

Now, I export this chart to an SVG. When I open the SVG (e.g. in MS Edge or in InkScape) - instead of a white glow, I get this weird straight-angle wedge shape which looks like the glow area - but not surrounding my text:

[image]

is there a way to get the glow to export properly? Or some reasonable alternative effect I could use, which does look fine when exported into SVG?

Answer (score 0):

Go through Adobe pdf.

In Excel: Save as Adobe PDF.  Save chart as separate tab.

In Inkscape: File > Import [Ctrl+I]. Default settings are fine.

Resize document to chart: File > Document Properties [Shift+Ctrl+D]> Resize page to content... [z] > Resize page to drawing or selection [r]

Save as SVG [Shift+Ctrl+S]

Comment: Interesting... but wouldn't I have to buy something from Adobe to do this?

Comment: Excel has Save As PDF.  I've Adobe Writer and (NitroPDF) on all my machines so I can't comment, but I use Inkscape and PDF to go from everything to SVG.